# How does multivariate entropy scale with a constant multiplier to one of the dimensions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

I want to know how multivariate [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) depends on scaling one of its dimensions. Namely, I want to know if there is a way to simplify the expression

$$H(\alpha X, Y, Z, ...)$$

as a function of a positive constant $\alpha$ for an arbitrary multivariate probability distribution. I am mostly interested in the 2D case, but a general $n$-dimensional case would also be great to understand. According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy#Properties_of_differential_entropy), the result for 1D is

$$H(\alpha X) = H(X) + \log(|\alpha|)$$

and for arbitrary matrix multiplication is

$$H(A X) = H(X) + \log(|\det A|)$$

with a link to Cover and Thomas page 253. However, [Cover and Thomas](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ecgong821/Wiley.Interscience.Elements.of.Information.Theory.Jul.2006.eBook-DDU.pdf) do not give proof for the second equation. If possible, I would appreciate a proof of the general case.

Comment: Isn't what you are asking a special case of the general result with $A=diag(\alpha, 1,1, \ldots,1)$?

Comment: @Stelios yes, it is. I just want the proof. I have to know for sure if this result is true in all cases, or if there are some assumptions about the underlying random variables

Comment: Did you try to show this? Do you understand the proof of the 1-D case? Do you remember how change of variables works in multivariate calculus?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 yes, I understand the 1D proof. I understand how to change variables in multivariate integrals. I struggle a bit with change of variables with respect to the probability distribution. I assume that something like this should be true, but I don't fully understand why: $f_y(y) = \frac{f_x(A^{-1}x)}{|\det(A)|}$

Comment: By definition, for any measurable $S$, $$ P(Y \in S) = \int_S f_Y(y) \,\mathrm{d}y.$$ But, if $Y = AX$, then $$ P(Y \in S) = P(X \in A^{-1}S) = \int_{x \in A^{-1}(S)} f_X(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{y \in S} f_X(A^{-1}y) |\det(A^{-1})| \,\mathrm{d}y.$$ Since these hold for every $S$, we have that $f_Y(y) = f_X(A^{-1}y) |\det(A^{-1})| $ almost everywhere w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: If you want intuition instead of a proof - the high level idea is that probabilities must be preserved under a map. So if we have a bijective map (like an invertible linear transform), then we upon considering infinitesimal regions at $y$ and at $x = A^{-1}y$, we must have $$ f_Y(y)\,|\mathrm{d}y| = f_X(x)\,|\mathrm{d}x|.$$ But since $x = A^{-1}y,$ we have  $|\mathrm{d}x| = |\det(A^{-1})| |\mathrm{d}y|.$ (This is of course very sloppy, but I think it captures the intuition nicely).